# Mongodb doesn't save data

Tags: mongodb, localhost

that's my first question.
I've set mongodb on my pc(win7). But there's one problem: when I close both windows(server - client), my data dont save at all. Well, collection names are saved, but i dont see othere data, belonged to collections.

Comment: Check /data/db directories when you close server-client. To run mongodb those directories are required and data is stored in those directories.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? Can you include an example of how you are saving the data and checking that the data has been saved?